Could not find any Python installation to use + node-gyp failed to rebuild when building Electron app
I'm trying to build my Electron APP and I'm getting the following errors:
⨯ Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
...
 node-gyp failed to rebuild '...node_modules\@parcel\watcher' 

I tried to install Python, set ENV Variables etc but nothing really helps. Any suggestions?
EDIT Here is my project package file - any suspicious thing here?
package.json


{
  "name": "math-wizards-desktop-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist-electron/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:react": "vite",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:react dev:electron",
    "dev:electron": "npm run transpile:electron && cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron .",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "transpile:electron": "tsc --project src/electron/tsconfig.json",
    "dist:mac": "npm run transpile:electron && npm run build && electron-builder --mac --arm64",
    "dist:win": "npm run transpile:electron && npm run build && electron-builder --win --x64",
    "dist:linux": "npm run transpile:electron && npm run build && electron-builder --linux --x64",
    "test:e2e": "playwright test",
    "test:unit": "vitest src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.62.7",
    "axios": "^1.7.9",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.7",
    "framer-motion": "^11.14.4",
    "lucide-react": "^0.468.0",
    "node-gyp": "^11.0.0",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "os-utils": "^0.0.14",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.4.0",
    "react-responsive-masonry": "^2.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.83.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.49.1",
    "@radix-ui/colors": "^3.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.15",
    "@types/node": "^22.10.2",
    "@types/os-utils": "^0.0.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-responsive-masonry": "^2.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^33.2.1",
    "electron-builder": "^25.1.8",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.49",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.16",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.9",
    "vitest": "^2.1.8",
    "windy-radix-palette": "^2.0.0-beta.7"
  }
}

========================================================================================================================================

Operating system? Assuming windows cause of slashes?

Also how did you install python?

windows 11 and I install Python from official website (newest version)

The build was working but then I started to expand the project with new packages etc and the mentioned error appeared - I added how my package.json file looks like

LOL sass package is problematic here for some reason... Why cant I use it?

Try installing python from the Microsoft store instead?

I encountered the same error, but after uninstalling the sass package, everything started working again.
